# Open form from SSRS Report

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, reporting-services

I don't know if is it possible, but could I click a row and then open a form from my project and use the row clicked as parameters to the form.

Is that possible to do?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What sort of form are you looking to open? You can open URL links etc and yes, you can pass the row value as a parameter

Comment: I need to pass parameters to a Windows Form.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form can take parameters on the URL then you can do this.

You need to set up the url as a navigation link. Let's say you want to pass the customer details to your form. So your field expression will simply be `Fields!CustomerName.Value` like normal. To turn the field into a navigatable link, right-click the cell, select `Text Box Properties...` then `Action`. Select the `Go to URL` radiobutton and enter your URL for your form:

```
="http://myserver/myform?CustomerID=" & Fields!CustomerID.Value & "&Name=" & Fields!CustomerName.Value
```

This will turn the displayed field in the cell into a clickable link that passes the customer id and name to the form on the URL.

I also change the `Font.Color` to `Blue` to indicate it is a link.

Comment: Thank's for the advice, but what I need is to pass parameters to Windows Form. I think thisn't possible.

Comment: @Yadder Aceituno I think your first question should be how to pass parameters to your Windows Form before you focus on doing so from SSRS.